# How should I handle user prescriptions? (eye glasses store)

Tags: attributes, orders, extensions, customer

I am struggling with a good backend approach. Each order item will need an Rx associated with it, and it should also be accessible/editable from the customer account page.

Should I make this its own EAV? Would this be better off a customer attribute or an order attribute? Any guidance or a similar extension to get me started would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would handle this with resource models that map to custom tables. No doubtedly you'll be asked to write some reporting or dashboards some day and having it in (flat-ish) tables with simple normalization will make it much easier than if you were to create as customer-centric EAV.

Comment: Interesting! That's a great idea. So have something like a rx_item table that maps to customer, order_item IDs?

Comment: Precisely. This is how magento handles all sorts of things like wishlists and registry